# Two quick questions regarding styling and importing TabNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native and i'm learning the basics.

Building my first app I'm running across a problem. I'm running it on my S9 using expo

**Problem**

I'm trying to use navigation tabs, but when I try to `import MainTabNavigator from './navigation/MainTabNavigator';`

I get the following error:

```
[22:46:34] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RootStack

This error is located at:
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
* App.js:17:9 in render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8811:23 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12924:25 in performUnitOfWork
- ... 16 more stack frames from framework internals
```

How come it does not find the `Rootstack`? Even though I imported it.

Also I've tried applying

```
tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
```

To `const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator`

But it doesn't return the styling, but rather seems to not recognize it.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainTabNavigator from './navigation/MainTabNavigator';


export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <RootStack />;
    }
}
```

**MainTabNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform,View, Text, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',


    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
} 

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Settings',
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Settings Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class WalletsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Wallet',

    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Wallet Screen</Text> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({ 

    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Wallet: {
        screen: WalletsScreen,
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: SettingsScreen,
    },


});


const RootStack = createStackNavigator({

    Home1: {
        screen: Tab,

    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are no exporting RootStack. Please try this and let me know:

```
export const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home1: {
    screen: Tab,
  },
});
```

and when you try to import do it like this:

```
import {RootStack} from './navigation/MainTabNavigator'
```

if you want to export everything of MainTabNavigator in one line add this at the end of the file:

```
export { RootStack, Tab}
```

For the styling question please post your complete code to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know if this works when I start again tonight.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. So if I want to use code from file A into file B, I have to export the function in A and import it in B makes sense.

Comment: Yes you have to export it. Regards